# Why when I open Site.css in ASP MVC Visual Studio restarts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, visual-studio-2012

I have an internet application project in ASP MVC and when I open site.css in the content folder, Visual Studio restarts. I have not changed anything in site.css.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: That is the problem in VS 2010 and has been fixed in VS 2012. This link may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962136/opening-bootstrap-min-css-crashes-vs2010